# Question about proof of connected subspace then separations contains no limit points of each other

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

"If $Y$ is a subspace of $X$, a separation of $Y$ is a pair of disjoint nonempty sets $A$ and $B$ neither of which contains limit points of the other. The space $Y$ is connected if there is no separation for it."

A part of the proof follows like this:

The closure of $A$ in $Y$ is $\overline{A}\cap Y$, where $\overline{A}$ is the closure of $A$ in $X$ (1). Since $A$ is closed, we have $A = \overline{A}\cap Y$ or to the say the same thing, $\overline{A}\cap B = \emptyset$ (2). Since $\overline{A}$ is the union of $A$ and its limit points, $B$ contains no limit points of $A$

In (1), is the closure of $A$ in $Y$ the set $\overline{A}\cap Y$, by definition?

In (2), how he concluded that $\overline{A}\cap B$

Comment: $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $Y$, aren't?

Comment: @rdias yes_____

Comment: I think it works now, sorry about the long edit in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(1) I think there is a proposition about closed sets in induced topology that states the closure of a set in a subset of the space is this intersection.

(2) holds because $$(A\cap B = \varnothing \text{ and } A=\overline{A}\cap Y)$$ implies $$\varnothing = A\cap B = (\overline{A}\cap Y)\cap B$$
$$= \overline{A}\cap (Y\cap B) = \overline{A}\cap B$$

**Edit:** The closure of a set $A$ in a topological space $X$ is $$\overline{A}=\bigcap\{F\subset X: A\subset F, \;F\text{ is closed in }X\}.$$ Let's denote the closure of $A$ in a subset $Y\subset X$ by $\overline{A}^Y$. Then
$$\overline{A}^Y = \bigcap\{C\subset Y: A\subset C,\;C\text{ is closed in } Y\}.$$
But a set $C$ is closed in $Y\subset X$ if there exists a set $D$ closed in $X$ such that $C=D\cap Y$. So
$$\overline{A}^Y = \bigcap\{D\cap Y: A\subset D,\;D\text{ is closed in } X\}$$
$$= Y\cap (\bigcap\{D: A\subset D,\;D\text{ is closed in } X\})$$
$$= Y\cap\overline{A}.$$

This explains number (1).